# Adding mileage markers to a GPX track

Tags: qgis, gpx

I don't even know where to begin.

I have a GPX track loaded in QGIS and I'd like to add markers at say every 5 miles. The track is about 70 miles long. Nicest would be little boxes with a number, but any kind of tick mark would be OK.

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: See here for a similar discussion: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69949/add-points-for-every-100-m-at-polyline-qgis-mapinfo

Comment: Thank you. I'll make further comments in that thread.

Comment: Will do. Trying to figure out how to change the CRS without having the GPS track disappear. Am able to use QChainage to put markers in but the units appear to be degrees

Comment: Yeah CRS is kind of a hangup for me as will with QGIS. See here for some details: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/how-can-i-change-the-projection-of-shapefile-in-qgis